# Is it good practice to use ApplicationLifetime events for Simple Injector container verification and disposal

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, simple-injector

Is it a good idea to do the following?

```
public void Configure(
    IApplicationBuilder app,
    IWebHostEnvironment env,
    IHostApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
{
    applicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() => _container.Verify());
    applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(() => _container.Dispose());
    ...
}
```

I'm wondering if there are edge cases in this pattern that cause verification to be executed too late or too early and if a failed verification leads to an application stop (hopefully it does).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to calling `Dispose`, with the introduction of [v4.9](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/releases/tag/v4.9) of the Simple Injector ASP.NET Core integration, the `Container` is automatically disposed of when the application shuts down. See [this documentation section](https://simpleinjector.org/servicecollection+disposing) for more information.

If you're using a version lower than v4.9, you might want to consider upgrading. It that's not possible, the use of `ApplicationStopped.Register` seems like a good idea.

I can't really comment on the `Verify()` behavior, so I'm interested in your experiences with this, although I see no advantage over calling `Verify` in the `Configure` method.

Comment: It turns out that putting the `Verify` in `applicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register` has a very nasty side-effect: the application just continues to run when verification fails. We decided to put the call in the `Configure` instead.

Comment: Hi @AroglDarthu, I must confess that I cheated a bit. That documentation section that I linked to in my answer... although the feature existed, the documentation was missing. I've been creating and publishing this in the time between your question and my answer. Thanks to your question I realized that there was a gap in the documentation.